# What would be the best way to display a variable search in HTML

Tags: search, html5

I have a search function with 5 different variables, the search depends on any one of the 5 variables. What would be the best way to display this without taking to much real estate and without it looking sloppy and budged in together.

I was thinking maybe popping the whole thing in a modal popup, but then what if I want multiple searches on one page it wouldn't be ideal for modal's. Essentially I would want an effective way to display this in my page, and be able to duplicate it on other pages as a default search type control.
This is what I currently have and the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/CHhyL/):

```
        <table class="table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Variable 1:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Variable 2:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Variable 3:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Variable 4:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Variable 5:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's only going to be five options, why not a dropdown menu + text input + submit button?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHhyL/1/)

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/7DSbY/